# Insert grid into the panelbar dynamically in kendoui

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI.
I am able to load the panel bar dynamically.now i want to insert the grid into the panelbar .If i click on the panel bar header,inside the header i have to display the grid and i want to load the grid dynamically.

Any suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

You could bind a callback to an appropriate event in the PanelBar, like `select` or `expand`, and load the grid in the callback.

Something like this (had no time to test...):

```
var panelBar = $("#panelBar").data("kendoPanelBar");
// bind the error ajax event
panelBar.bind("expand", function(e) {
    $(e.item).kendoGrid();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/rQZNr/21/), although the accordion doesn't work in the fiddle, it works when I run the coding locally. I think something is just linked wrong, but the coding works!.

For example, I count the number of occurances in the dataSource and then I created a loop to run that number of times, where I created a grid inside the loop.

This works the same as a loop:

```
$(doc).find("component").each(function (x, component) 
{
    $("#gridGenerate" + x).kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: function (op) {
                console.log("read");
                return op.success(gridDataArray);
            }
        },
        pageSize : 9
    }
});
```

Hope this is useful.